# chef workstation conectivity

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-devops, devops

```
[root@ip-172-31-37-35 .chef]# knife ssl check
/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/proxifier-1.0.3/lib/uri/socks.rb:8:in `<module:URI>': uninitialized class variable @@schemes in URI (NameError)
        from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/proxifier-1.0.3/lib/uri/socks.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from <internal:/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/proxifier-1.0.3/lib/proxifier.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from <internal:/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.0.185/lib/chef/mixin/proxified_socket.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from <internal:/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/knife-18.0.185/lib/chef/knife/ssl_check.rb:33:in `block in <class:SslCheck>'
        from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/knife-18.0.185/lib/chef/knife.rb:245:in `each'
        from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/knife-18.0.185/lib/chef/knife.rb:245:in `load_deps'
        from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/knife-18.0.185/lib/chef/knife.rb:230:in `run'
        from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/knife-18.0.185/lib/chef/application/knife.rb:165:in `run'
        from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/knife-18.0.185/bin/knife:24:in `<top (required)>'
        from /bin/knife:400:in `load'
        from /bin/knife:400:in `<main>'
[root@ip-172-31-37-35 .chef]# ^C
[root@ip-172-31-37-35 .chef]#



cookbook_path            ["#{current_dir}/../cookbooks"]
[root@ip-172-31-37-35 .chef]# knife ssl check
/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/proxifier-1.0.3/lib/uri/socks.rb:8:in `<module:URI>': uninitialized class variable @@schemes in URI (NameError)
        from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/proxifier-1.0.3/lib/uri/socks.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from <internal:/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/proxifier-1.0.3/lib/proxifier.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from <internal:/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/chef-18.0.185/lib/chef/mixin/proxified_socket.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from <internal:/opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
        from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/knife-18.0.185/lib/chef/knife/ssl_check.rb:33:in `block in <class:SslCheck>'
        from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/knife-18.0.185/lib/chef/knife.rb:245:in `each'
        from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/knife-18.0.185/lib/chef/knife.rb:245:in `load_deps'
        from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/knife-18.0.185/lib/chef/knife.rb:230:in `run'
        from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/knife-18.0.185/lib/chef/application/knife.rb:165:in `run'
        from /opt/chef-workstation/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/knife-18.0.185/bin/knife:24:in `<top (required)>'
        from /bin/knife:400:in `load'
        from /bin/knife:400:in `<main>'
[root@ip-172-31-37-35 .chef]# ^C
[root@ip-172-31-37-35 .chef]#
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

This error is bug in chef's newer versions.
Try to install older versions of chef workstation like :-
**22.10.1013** or earlier to this version

[Check below version for your reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tv1yH.jpg)